# What exactly these tr commnads do?

Tags: quoting, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tr

I am rewriting some commands that were run using WSL on a Windows machine and need to accomplish the same thing in Python. I am having a really hard time figuring out what exactly these commands are accomplishing.

Here are the commands and what I have figured out about them so far:

1. `wsl tr -dc \'\\007-\\011\\012-\\015\\040-\\376\' < some.txt > someother.txt` - I think this command uses ranges of octal escape sequences to remove some junk characters from some.txt. But again, I am having a hard time figuring out exactly what characters and where in the text file they are removed.
2. `wsl tr -d \'\\333\' < someother.txt > some.txt` - this one a complete mystery to me. I looked up octal 333 and it does even have ascii associated with it.
3. `wsl tr \"|\" \" \"` - this command is supposedly replacing certain pipe characters with spaces, but I am having a hard time figuring out which ones.

I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Looks like corrupted xfer from Windows. Your 1st command looks like an attempt to  pass a `tr -dc '[\007-\011\012-\040-376]'` to 'wsl`, with the "funny" characters "\-escaped". Read `man tr ascii` to learn about `-d ` (delete) and `-c ` (complement (invert)) options.

Comment: @waltinator, don't need `[]` unless you want to explicitly save them too. The escaping seems off, though. In a POSIX shell, that last one would be a pipe where the right hand side runs a command called `"`. (I don't know about WSL though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently, these are not commands in the syntax of cmd, powershell or sh: there is an additional layer of backslash escaping. After doing this backslash escaping, we're left with the following sh commands:

```
wsl tr -dc '\007-\011\012-\015\040-\376' < some.txt > someother.txt
wsl tr -d '\333' < someother.txt > some.txt
wsl tr "|" " "
```

The first two commands read from a file and write to a file. The last one reads from standard input and writes to standard output.

In a non-option argument to `tr`, a backslash followed by three octal digits represents the byte whose value is given by the digits. An ASCII hyphen (`-`) between two bytes means any byte whose value is between those two, inclusive.

The first command passes the following two arguments to `tr`: `-dc` and `\007-\011\012-\015\040-\376`. `-dc` means to remove every byte¹ except the ones whose value is given in the following argument. In other words, the indicated bytes are kept, and all others are discarded. The bytes that are kept are:

- `\007-\011\012-\015`: bytes with values 7 through 13, i.e. the [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart) [BEL (bell)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character), [BS (backspace)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace), [HT (horizontal tab)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_Tab), [LF (line feed)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Feed), [VT (vertical tab)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_Tab), [FF (form feed)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_Feed) and [CR (carriage return)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_Return). By the way, a Windows line ending is the two-character sequence CR LF, whereas a Unix line ending is the single character LF.
- `\040-\376`: this encompasses all [printable ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) as well as the mostly unused
  character 127 and all non-ASCII characters except for some reason 255. The byte value 255 does not appear in UTF-8, but is an ordinary character in many legacy 8-bit character sets.

So this is a somewhat quirky way of removing control characters except for all the ones that are whitespace and a couple that aren't, and also removing byte 255 which some buggy software interprets as end-of-file.

The second command passes the following two arguments to `tr`: `-d` and `\333`. It removes (`-d`) the byte `\333` (219 in decimal, 0xdb in hexadecimal). I have no idea why one might want to remove this particular byte value.

The third command passes the following arguments to `tr`: `|` and   (a space). This replaces each occurrence of the character `|` (ASCII vertical line, a.k.a. pipe) by an ordinary ASCII space. This replaces all occurrences of `|`, not just “certain” ones.

In Python, you can use:

1. [`import re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) then `re.sub(rb'\000-\006\016-\037\377', rb'', x)`, or [`bytes.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.maketrans) followed by [x.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.translate)
2. [`x.replace(b'\333'. b'')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.replace)
3. [`x.replace(b'|'. b' ')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.replace)

¹  <sub>Some implementations of `tr` support multibyte characters, but not GNU `tr`, which as far as I know is the one supplied with WSL.</sub>